# libgdx actor input not working

Tags: java, libgdx, actor, stage

My actor in libgdx draws normally how ever the inputlistener is not working, i have checked that i initiated the Gdx.input.setInputProcessor and i'm pretty sure that my bounds are set correctly so please help me with this issue.

Code:

```
Sprite playButton = new Sprite(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("badlogic.jpg")));


public playBtn(){
    setBounds(playButton.getX(),playButton.getY(),getWidth(),getHeight());
    setTouchable(Touchable.enabled);
    addListener(new InputListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            Gdx.app.log("Example", "touch started at (" + x + ", " + y + ")");
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public void touchUp (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            Gdx.app.log("Example", "touch done at (" + x + ", " + y + ")");
        }

    });



}

@Override
public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
    playButton.draw(batch);


}

@Override
public void act(float delta) {
    super.act(delta);
}
```

Main class:

```
    public MenuState(GameStateManager gsm){
    super(gsm);


    ScreenViewport screenViewport = new ScreenViewport();
    menuStage = new Stage(screenViewport);
    playBtn playButton= new playBtn();
    menuStage.addActor(playButton);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(menuStage);



    background = new Sprite(new Texture("MenuBG.png"));
    project = new Project();
    background.setSize(project.WIDTH,project.HEIGHT);


}


@Override
protected void handleInput() {

}

@Override
public void update(float dt) {
    handleInput();

}



@Override
public void render(SpriteBatch sb) {



    sb.begin();
    background.draw(sb);
    sb.end();
    menuStage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
    menuStage.draw();

}
```

Comment: "the inputlistener is not working" doesn't help that much. You might want to explain in what ways it is not working. Does it do the wrong things? Doesn't it get called at all? Additionally you might want to clean up your posted code a bit to make it easier to read.

Comment: @Thomas Yeah sure i'll edit it once more, and the inputlistener does not get called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
setBounds(playButton.getX(), playButton.getY(), playButton.getWidth(), playButton.getHeight())
```